# How to pass table name dynamically in DAX formula

Tags: dax

I would like to call the table name dynamically from a different table. But the DAX formula I used below is not really catering to my needs. Anyone can help me with this, please?

```
m-AvgVolume % = 
VAR tableName = 
    SELECTEDVALUE(gnr_projects[TableName])
RETURN 
    SUM(tableName[Volume])
```

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Probably not possible directly, but you could set up a SWITCH function to handle all the possible cases.